# Making Login with VBS and connecting to SQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, vbscript, cmd

So, I am trying to make a small program for all my programs.
I have made a site that alot of kids at my school use. Reason being my site has some little programs I have made they like to use. Such as a Proxy so they can all get on Reddit, Facebook, etc. along with a Messanger that lets them send files to and fro (i.e , Home work).

So instead of making them all download each program, I wanted to make a full fledged "Hub."
I am making it in VBS & Batch because thats what all my programs are and people seem to like them because they are simple, so I stick with it. I know how to make a launchers and such, because I spend alot of time developing on Fiesta Online Private Servers. But like I said, they like the whole Batch thing.

I am going to be hosting my SQL server to one of my dedicated servers, I know how to set up SQL Server, and OBDC and all that. I just want to know a few things.

How can link them to my "Hub" in VBS format, reason being I am still trying to make a Login system. Once I get it working on this program, I will use the same SQL database people use for the program for my website I am in the process of coding. Because the current site was a simple Webs.com site and I never thought my little programs would be popular.

**NOTE THE LOCATION OF THIS FOLDER IS HOW OUR SCHOOL COMPUTERS ARE SET UP.. SO IGNORE THE FOLDER LOCATION**
ps. I got this code off a site, Not all of it, just a starting point, I have put ALOT into it thought (my attempt at a login system .-. & Such..)

```
@echo off
title Program
color B
mode con: cols=51 lines=18
IF NOT EXIST "H:\My Documents\Program\data\uname.txt" goto SIGNUP
IF NOT EXIST "H:\My Documents\Program\data\password.txt" goto SIGNUP
goto LOGIN

:SIGNUP
title SignUp
cls
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo                     SignUp
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo.
set/p "unamesu=Enter Username : "
set/p "passsu=Enter Password : "
echo.
echo.
IF ["%unamesu%"] == [""] goto SIGNUPERROR
IF ["%passsu%"] ==[""] goto SIGNUPERROR
goto CREATEACC

:SIGNUPERROR
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo                     Error
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo Invalid Username or password
pause
goto SIGNUP

:CREATEACC
Sub CreateAfile
   Dim fso, MyFile
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile("H:\My Documents\Program\data\uname.txt", True)
   MyFile.WriteLine("%unamesu%")
   MyFile.Close
End Sub
Sub CreateAfile
   Dim fso, MyFile
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile("H:\My Documents\Program\data\password.txt", True)
   MyFile.WriteLine("%passsu%")
   MyFile.Close
End Sub
:LOGIN
set/p uname= < H:\My Documents\Program\data\uname.txt
set/p pass=< H:\My Documents\Program\data\password.txt
title Login
cls
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo                       Login
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
set/p "unamel=_               Username : "
set/p "passwordl=_               Password : "
echo.
IF "%unamel%"=="" goto LOGINERROR
IF "%passwordl"=="" goto LOGINERROR
IF NOT %unamel%==%uname% goto LOGINERROR
IF NOT %passwordl%==%pass% goto LOGINERROR
goto LOADING

:LOGINERROR
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo                     Error
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo Invalid Username or password
pause
goto LOGIN


:LOADING
title Loading...
set load=%load%!!!!!!!
cls
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo                       Login
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
echo                 Username : %unamel%
echo                 Password : %passwordl%
echo.
echo.
echo          Logging in...
echo          ===================================
echo          %load%
echo          ===================================
echo.                              Please Wait...
echo.
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
set/a loadnum=%loadnum% +1
if %loadnum%==5 goto DONE
goto LOADING

:DONE
title Done
cls
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo                       Done
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo. 
echo. 
echo.                Login Successfully
echo. 
echo. 
echo.
echo.
echo -------------------------------------------------
pause
GOTO HOME
:HOME
title Program Hub
cls
echo Welcome Back %unamesu%
ECHO 1 - Firewall Killer
ECHO 2 - Messanger
ECHO 3 - Go to Site
ECHO 4 - Exit
SET /P OPT=Please make a selection, and press enter:
if %OPT%==1 GOTO Firewall
if %OPT%==2 GOTO Message
if %OPT%==3 GOTO Website
if %opt%==4 GOTO Exit
:Firewall
cls
H:\My Documents\Program\data\Firewall.exe
GOTO Launch
:Message
Messenger.exe
exit
pause
:Website
strURL = "GOOGLE.COM"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run(strURL)
exit
pause
:Launch
cls
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo. 
echo. 
echo.                  Now Launching
echo. 
echo. 
echo.
echo.
echo -------------------------------------------------
pause
exit
:Exit
cls
SET /P EXI= Close Hub?
echo 1 - Cancle
echo 2 - Yes, Exit
if %EXI%==1 GOTO HOME
if %EXI%==2 GOTO CLOSE
:CLOSE
exit
```

Comment: First thing's first, you've got 2 sets of code going here. One set is in Windows batch file format, the other is in VBScript. You'll have to take the code that is in VBScript and place them in to .vbs files, and the code that is batch, and place them into .bat files. You can call your VBScript files from your batch files by executing them with cscript.exe. "cscript.exe myscript.vbs". Once you have a good file structure, you can work on modifying your code to do what you want.

Comment: I plan on taking all the codes from my other programs and adding them directly into this one. as of now they just have place holders that launch the programs them selves.

Comment: You shouldn't do that. You should use batch's CALL functionality to call each of your other programs. This is called modular code. It means that if there is a problem in one file it won't spill over into other programs. Keep your programs logically separate and in different files.

Comment: Thats a good point, now how do I link it to the Database, an how do I set it up to read User, and Pass 0.0.. cause i cant figure that out with txt files.

Comment: Well that depends. You can easily connect to databases with VBScript. You can pass arguments to your VBScript files too. You might call your VBScript file like this "cscript.exe yourscript.vbs username password". Then have your VBS run through it's logic to call the SQL database.

Comment: Mind leaving an example?

Comment: http://bit.ly/1lgDaAc

Comment: so the only DBs I have set up, are for a Private Server. Like, Account, GameLogs, Characters, etc. But I have never started one from scratch. how do I create said table for User, and Password.
or anyone who has used IPB forums, can I link them to my IPB DBs?

Comment: You should Google these questions. This website is for SPECIFIC programming related questions and not general ones. If you'd like to know how to create a table, Google "how do I create a table in a SQL database" instead of asking here. Before you ask a question you should ask the same question to Google and see if you can figure it out by reading first.

Comment: I have tried to google it, and Everytime I find somthing and test it, it doesnt work ( and yes I search the errors before moving on )
Sorry that I dont know how to do somthing an needed some help.

Comment: Post what you've tried.

Comment: I googled things like : SQL to VBS , SQL to Batch, connecting Database to batch file, SQL scripts for VBS/Batch. Etc

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=vbs+sql+tutorial